# Changing the place of 'not' affects meaning?

Tags: grammar

> (1) He is leaving **not** just the institute, but also mathematics.
>
> (2) He is **not** leaving just the institute, but also mathematics.

Does the second sentence imply that he is not going to leave any of them, so he is staying? At first glance they have the same meaning for me.

Comment: don't you need *not only* as a format in *not only... but also...*?

Comment: @MaulikV: A native speaker corrected the second (mine) to the first.

Comment: I also agree with the answers other people gave,but one thing I want to mention considering the above comment of OP.I think in conversation your first sentence is ok,with a pause before "not". Like this "He is leaving,...not just the institute, but also mathematics". I think other than that, there is no possibility of your first sentence to be correct.Every language follows some word arrangements,and thanks to grammar it's been possible for non-native speakers to understand the language.If you say "I not boy a",it doesn't mean anything unless and until you change it to its correct arrangement.

Comment: @Man_From_India The first sentence is grammatical.  I agree with your point that grammar is important, but if the grammar you've learned rules out sentence #1, then it is in need of some slight revision.  The structure is as follows: "He is leaving [ **not just** *the institute*, **but also** *mathematics* ]"  Here, the negator *not* is not attached to a verb; if it were, it would have to be attached to the auxiliary *is*.  We don't say "He walks not", but "He doesn't walk" because negators don't attach to lexical verbs. But "He walks [ **not** *to the store*, **but** *to his home* ]" is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence seems to me merely a slightly more difficult to parse version of the first. It doesn't imply he's not leaving when it has the 'just' and 'but' conjunction. Without 'but...', maybe it could be made to mean he's not leaving. But that phrase makes it clear he's leaving, just takes a few milliseconds longer to figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

I think the format goes like ...

> ....**not** only **X**, **but also Y** OR ...**not** just **X**, **but also Y**

Here, in this format, *X* and *Y* are **usually grammatically parallel.**

> ...**not** only **X** (noun), **but also Y** (noun) OR ...**not** only **X** (verb), **but also Y** (verb)

Examples -

> He is **not** only a **doctor** (X), ***but also a player** (Y): X and Y both are nouns. 
>   He was **not** just **eating** (X), **but also crying** (Y): X and Y both are verbs.

But then that's not the issue in first sentence. In the second case if 'Y' is noun, 'X' should be the noun as well and your second sentence makes the verb 'leaving' as 'X'.

> He is leaving **not** just the **institute** (X), **but also mathematics** (Y) - X and Y both are nouns 
>   He is **not leaving** (X) just the institute, **but also mathematics** (Y) - X is verb and Y is noun. **Note that** the placement of only/just is also not with *not* what the general format says.

Does the second sentence imply that he is not going to leave any of them, so he is staying? - **No, it does not mean that.**

Both the sentences mean the same (that he's leaving both - the institute and mathematics) and anyone would understand that but still, I'd prefer...

> He's leaving not just the institute, but also mathematics.